# Connect to a WCF web service without WCF

Tags: asp.net, web-services

We have an ASP.NET 2.0 site.  A 3rd party has created a web service that we are supposed to connect to, and I was naively expecting a 2.0 style web service to be created.  When I was given the url, I was expecting to see a .asmx suffix...but instead was given a url with .svc suffix.

Going to that page tells me to to create a WCF client by running svcutil...but, again, we aren't running .NET 3.0+ yet.

Since it's a web service, I'm thinking the basic functionality should be essentially the same, but freely admit I know essentially nothing about WCF (yet.)

Can I expect this to work eventually, or is there some kind of potentially blocking issue (WCF web services being inherently different in some profound way)?  Is there a simple path for creating a basic client (like svcutil would if we were in the 3.0+ world)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's using BasicHttpBinding (SOAP 1.1) it's probably interoperable.

In the "Add Service Reference" dialog in VS2010, click on "Advanced", then click on the "Add Web Reference" button.

Comment: Well, we have VS2005, because we're still in the 2.0 world...which led me to believe that it would not understand how to create the service connection.  However, since, as you mentioned it's probably using the same underlying protocol (SOAP 1.1), it makes sense that it might work...and it seems to!  Thanks!